# Chart with multiple groups

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I got the following table on Google Sheets.
[image]

I want the first column to represent the groups in x axis.
The 2nd column is supposed to be the a group in a certain x value
lets say I have:

```
8 3 22

8 4 55
 
8 5 72
```

I want to have at value x = 8 , 3 bars, the first bar has the y value of 22 with the label 3, the 2nd  has y value of 22 with label 4, and the 3rd has y value of 72 with label 5.

This is the chart I got which is completely not the one I wanted.
[image]

Comment: What was wrong with the answer to this _identical_ question? [Multiple Groups Graph on Google Sheets. Please Help](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/148572/196152) - also on webapps, posted by you on 2 Nov 2020

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple Groups Graph on Google Sheets. Please Help](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/148264/multiple-groups-graph-on-google-sheets-please-help)