# Multiple Groups Graph on Google Sheets. Please Help

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I got the following table on google sheets. [image]

---

**Text version**

```
+----+---+---+----+
|    | A | B | C  |
+----+---+---+----+
| 1  | 1 | 2 | 1  |
+----+---+---+----+
| 2  | 2 | 1 | 1  |
+----+---+---+----+
| 3  | 3 | 1 | 4  |
+----+---+---+----+
| 4  | 3 | 2 | 7  |
+----+---+---+----+
| 5  | 3 | 3 | 8  |
+----+---+---+----+
| 6  | 3 | 4 | 1  |
+----+---+---+----+
| 7  | 4 | 1 | 3  |
+----+---+---+----+
| 8  | 4 | 2 | 4  |
+----+---+---+----+
| 9  | 4 | 3 | 13 |
+----+---+---+----+
| 10 | 4 | 4 | 1  |
+----+---+---+----+
| 11 | 4 | 5 | 3  |
+----+---+---+----+
| 12 | 5 | 3 | 5  |
+----+---+---+----+
| 13 | 5 | 4 | 14 |
+----+---+---+----+
| 14 | 5 | 5 | 5  |
+----+---+---+----+
| 15 | 5 | 3 | 8  |
+----+---+---+----+
| 16 | 6 | 4 | 27 |
+----+---+---+----+
| 17 | 6 | 5 | 16 |
+----+---+---+----+
| 18 | 5 | 5 | 1  |
+----+---+---+----+
| 19 | 7 | 4 | 4  |
+----+---+---+----+
| 20 | 7 | 5 | 1  |
+----+---+---+----+
| 21 | 8 | 3 | 2  |
+----+---+---+----+
| 22 | 8 | 4 | 72 |
+----+---+---+----+
| 23 | 8 | 5 | 55 |
+----+---+---+----+
```

---

I want the first column to represent the groups in x axis. The 2nd column is supposed to be the a group in a certain x value lets say I have

8 3 22

8 4 55

8 5 72

I want to have at value x = 8 , 3 bars, the first bar has the y value of 22 with the label 3, the 2nd has y value of 22 with label 4, and the 3rd has y value of 72 with label 5.

This is the chart I got which is completely not the one I wanted.

[image]

Comment: Welcome. Would you please add a brief description of your own search/research efforts as is suggested in [How do I ask a good question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and also describe your own efforts to solve your problem. Regarding the formatting of the graph, you've shown the layout that you do NOT want. Would you please edit your question to display the layout (hand-drawn?) that you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Please use [plain text](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) for your table not images

Answer (score 0):

Format your chart as follows:

- Highlight cells A1:C23
- From the Main menu, choose `Insert, Insert Chart`.
- Double-click the chart and make the following changes:
- **Setup**

  - Chart Type: Column Chart
  - Stacking: None
  - Data Range: A1:C23 (for confirmation)
  - X-Axis: A1:A23 (for confirmation)
  - Series:

    - B1:B23 - Remove
    - C1:C23 - Add Labels, select the range B1:B23
- **Customise**

  - Chart & axis titles

    - Edit according to your needs
  - Horizontal Axis

    - Treat labels as text - Tick the box
  - Vertical Axis

    - Treat labels as text - Tick the box if not already ticked
    - Show Axis Line - Tick the box if not already ticked
  - Gridlines and ticks
  - Vertical Axis

    - Major gridlines - Tick the box if not already ticked
    - Minor gridlines - Tick the box if not already ticked
    - Major ticks - Tick the box if not already ticked

---

**Chart**

[image: Chart]